# Grant side developers a partial access to a git repo

Tags: git, repository, partial

Until now, I've been working on a project with a single and reliable agency.

However, I'd now like to speed up development by entrusting a few subjects to side developers. That means they need to access the repo, though I don't want them to get access to critical code.

Is there a way to grant them only a partial access to the repo (only the files I decided to show them), or to create (and maintain) a side repository, which doesn't includes some files/folders that I want to keep unknown to them ?

In other terms, I'd like these side developpers to work on the repo without granting them access to critical assets.

Answer (score 2):

One approach is to *[Set Up a Submodule Where Only You Have Write Access](http://365git.tumblr.com/post/12581972612/set-up-a-submodule-where-only-you-have-write)*:

> Say you want to add a submodule to your repository, and this submodule is a one to which you have push access. It is frequently useful to be able to publish a repository with the submodule URL as pull-only, while keeping the push-pull URL in your own repository. This way, you can make changes to the submodule repository from within the enclosing repository. This is a simple thing to do in Git once you know how submodules are arranged.

Answer (score 1):

Despite my other answer I would actually recommend NOT using git submodules.  They are confusing and not well understood.  I've seen organizations use them and then yank them out afterwards.

I would personally consider using separate repos.  I would add one task (shell script say) that combines (copies) the code into one place for use.  I'd create an alias or function (allows parameters) to do this task

Comment: Thanks for your reply. So, to be sure I got what you meant : a proper workflow would be to set a side repo, that I would feed through a shell script, which strictly copies the folders or files I am willing to add ?

Comment: Yes that's what I might do.  I might also tie into pre/post commit/push hooks so this is done automatically.

Comment: You mean that a post push hook on the main repository could be used to automate the update of the side one ?

Comment: Yes.  It could also then cd to that directory and add, commit, push, though I would be hesitant about that.  Sometimes you can over-automate.